# SQL results returned in tablename.fieldname format

Tags: sql

When I run a query that is selecting fields from multiple tables, i.e. for a join, I would do something like:

```
SELECT table1.field1, table2.field2 FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1;
```

When the results of a query like this is returned the array only has the field names as the index, not the combination of tablename.fieldname, and I am wondering if it is possible to get it to return the data in this format because it is required by a plugin that I use.

Thank you.

EDIT: I thought of doing an alias, but the way that the plugin works is it takes the columns I give it literally, and then looks for those EXACT names in the array. Basically I give it the columns, it dynamically gets the data and displays it. So if I give it 'table1.field1 AS alias', it will look for that but the resulting field will be just 'alias'.

**EDIT 2**: I found a solution to my problem, it was not a SQL solution. I manipulated the resulting array of the query with PHP to get it back into the format that I needed to be in.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use alias for columns.

Comment: Do you mean doing SELECT table1.field1 AS alias ...etc... If this is what you mean, I have thought of doing that, but the way that the plugin works is it takes the columns I give it literally, and then looks for those EXACT names in the array. Basically I give it the columns, it dynamically gets the data and displays it. So if I give it 'table1.field1 AS alias', it will look for that but the resulting field will be just 'alias'.

Comment: @Key: **it will look for that but the resulting field will be just 'alias'** what you mean by this?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, if you look at my responses to M.R. it might clear it up a bit on what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it automatically. You can just alias them, though -

```
SELECT table1.field1 as [table1.field1], table2.field2 as [table2.field2] FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1
```

Comment: See my reply to Harry Joy, same problem thing. Even though that would answer my question...I probably should have been a bit more precise. I also edited my original question with that reply in mind.

Comment: not sure I understand. If your outputted alias is 'table1.field1', why wouldn't the plugin take THAT exactly? You're saying it strips out 'table1' part?

Comment: I use a jQuery table plugin to pass column names to a PHP script, and that script dynamically creates a query to get the requested data, then returns it to the plugin in JSON for display on the page. So for tables that need joins I must use the tablename.fieldname format, and then when the query runs the tablename is stripped out of the index in the array. So then when the jQuery plugin looks for the columns in the tablename.fieldname format, it can't find them because it is just the field name.

Comment: If I were to use an alias, I would tell it 'table1.field1 AS alias' for the column, and when the sql is run just the alias would be part of the array index, but the plugin would look for 'table1.field1 AS alias'. If that makes sense

Comment: Gotcha. I'm guessing you can't change the plugin?

Comment: So - this is a hack, normally I would change the plugin - but if you have no control over the plugin, and have other constraints, is it possible you can just change your field name in the table to be '[table1.field1]'? thats one option, the other is to make a calcualted field on the table, which will basically select field1 as table1.field1....

Comment: It is not my plugin, but the way I am manipulating it could be changed. I am trying to do it so dynamically because I have so many tables that it would be ridiculous to have a separate script file for each one. The plugin was not necessarily intended to pass the columns, even though it can be manipulated to do so. I will just have to re-analyze the best way to go about doing what I need done.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean changing the database table's field name, or the jQuery plugin table's field name? And how so?

Comment: This problem with the field name is only a problem because I am trying to use JSON, and for some reason the way the plugin uses the JSON formatted data the field names have to be the exact same as what was given to the script. I could just keep using XML like I have before, I was just thinking JSON would be easier as it cuts out alot of PHP code.

Comment: I found a PHP solution to manipulate the resulting query to get it back to what I need the indexes to be. I will mark this question for deletion because I don't see how it can benefit anyone else by staying up.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how many tables you have, but maybe you can add a calculated column on each table, which would be named 'table1.field1'. I didn't mean to suggest that you change the physical field name - changing the field name literally I think would cause problems in other areas of your application that uses the table....

Comment: Yes changing the literal field would probably require me having to go back to fix things like you suggest. The PHP solution I found was remarkably simple. The PHP script stores the columns passed to it by the jQuery plugin in an array at the beginning and never changes that array. So I just checked the results array against that array's indexes and replaced the corresponding index names so that it is back in the right format.